# Can not show youtube video fullscreen on iOS browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I am creating a custom player for youtube which is working perfectly on desktop browser and android browsers. I am using a package for this. Package name is: screenfull.

```
let iframe = document.querySelector(".videoContainer");

if(screenFull.enabled){
  if (!screenFull.isFullscreen) {
    screenFull.request(iframe);
  } else {
    screenFull.exit();
  }
}
```

but this is not working on iOS browsers as FullScreen API is not supported on iOS browsers. And after having a look on google search, I didn't find any solution for this.

```
<div className="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-center"  onClick={this._onFullScreen.bind(this)}>
   <span>
     <i className="fas fa-expand" />
   </span>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a hack for this ?

Comment: I am using click events here, updated the question with html element part. please have a look

Comment: Still no support on iOS: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: @somethinghere, yes I know that, mentioned in the question too. But running video from duckduckgo can still take us to fullscreen, so there must be a hack. 

I want to get an idea on that

Comment: All I get on DuckDuckGo is youtube, and I presume youtube is just using the `fullscreen` of a video element, which might still be allowed. Not sure about that, but if iOS doesn't want you fullscreen, there's probably no hack to achieve it.